# One source file providing multiple components

Tags: c, uml

I am trying to create a component diagram of an existing embedded software written in C. It happens to have a 3k+ lines C file which happens to use a lot of hardware-dependent components (memory-mapped peripherals, tiny bit of Assembly for the CPU) as well as lots of hardware-independent components. My problem is that it also provides lots of hardware-dependent and hardware-independent functionality.

I am wondering if I can split this file in several components in UML digram, in order to manage the interfaces in a better way. So the question is: **is it allowed to split one file in multiple components?**

The ultimate task of this exercise is to make a model of the system and then separate the parts of the code that are hardware-independent. That would help us to port this software to different architectures/SOCs/Boards. Breaking this file into multiple files *is* a possibility, but at the moment we need the actual architecture represented in the diagram.

Comment: "Allowed" by who? You are the designer, do whatever you want...

Comment: Be sure to look into SysML. It's been designed to deal exactly with that sort of embedded systems/C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as UML is concerned, yes, it is allowed. UML does not have any rules about how to model a piece of C source code. If you can discern multiple logical units in a large C file, then sure, you should model it as multiple components.